# Check if fonts are embedded in an existing PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-reader, pdf-rendering

How can I check if the `fonts` are embedded in an existing `PDF`?

That is, read an existing `PDF` and list out the results in a `.txt` file

I went through the following **example:**

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=287

The above example tries to create a **new PDF**, but I want to **read a `PDF`** file and check if the fonts are embedded or not.

I am more of a `PHP` guy so having a hard time to tweak the code. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The example indeed creates a new PDF using the `FontTypes` example, because the `ListUsedFonts` example needs a sample PDF to examine. If you take a look at the `listFonts()` method, you'll notice that *no PDF is created in that method.* Instead, an existing PDF of which the file path is `src` is read by `PdfReader`. There is no method inside `ListUsedFonts` that creates a new PDF. The `main()` method calls the `createPdf()` method in the `FontTypes` class, which is an example you don't need.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: Hi..Thanx a lot for your suggestion,please take a look at my answer, am I right what I have done?

Comment: I am getting the output though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what I have done is correct. Based on the suggestion by Bruno,

I actually removed the dependency of that `FontTypes` package itself.

Instead created a   new variable  `public static final String PREFACE = "resources/pdfs/sample.pdf";`//Path of Existing PDF File

And Passed the `PREFACE` to the main method

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Set<String> set = new ListUsedFonts().listFonts(PREFACE);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        for (String fontname : set)
            out.println(fontname);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

But I did get the output in the form `fonts.txt`